# What’s the correct way to disconnect this circuit board connector?

Tags: connector

Electronics noob here. What’s the correct way to unplug this cable from the circuit board? Don’t want to break it! Thanks.[image: Circuit board][image]

Comment: Are these latches on the extremities? Is there a latch mechanism on the inside of the board?

Comment: It looks like a typical rectangular header like a jst. You should be able to carefully just pull it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MadHatter also suggested, I also think this looks a JST connector, maybe from the SH connector series.

I unmount these SH connector using a sharp tweezer or two screwdrivers and **gently** pry loose the house from the header such that the house leaves the header as straight as possible.
I position the tweeser points between house and header on both sides as shown in the picture below (between the red lines on each side).

[image]

While gently prying the house one side, I try to fixate the tweezer pijt other side on the header, such that it acts fulcrum. Alternating this per tweezer point, I gently lift up the house bit by bit till it comes out.

For clarity, I drew and explained the process  using the long side of the connector.  Prying at the small sides of the connector might even go easier.

I think this method is always better than pulling on the leads of the connector.